# App crashing on iOS 16, but not iOS 17. -

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that allows you to take a photo using the device camera - once taken, it proceeds to the next screen, to edit - however, on iOS 16 devices, it crashes as soon as I press the 'Use photo' button from the camera view - it does not happen on iOS 17 devices for some reason, it works fine on them.
I tried to debug with no success.

```
#define IMAGE_FRAME_SIZE 5
#define FRAME_COLOR_R 1.0
#define FRAME_COLOR_G 1.0
#define FRAME_COLOR_B 1.0
#define FRAME_COLOR_ALPHA 1

//#define VIEW_AREA_WIDTH 320
//#define VIEW_AREA_HEIGHT 368
//#define IMAGEVIEW_MARGIN 20

#define VIEW_AREA_WIDTH         ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 768 : 320)
#define VIEW_AREA_HEIGHT        ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 800 : 368)
#define IMAGEVIEW_MARGIN        ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 40 : 20)
#define SHADOW_WIDTH            ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 16 : 8)


@interface PhotoSelectViewController ()

@end

@implementation PhotoSelectViewController

@synthesize popoverController;
@synthesize cameraPicker;
@synthesize backgroundImageView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
      
    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"background-568h@2x.png"]];
    else
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"background.png"]];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    
    [self.view setBounds:self.view.frame];
    
    backgroundImageView.image = [[[GlobalData compressImage:[GlobalData sharedData].backgroundImage withSize:CGSizeMake((VIEW_AREA_WIDTH - IMAGEVIEW_MARGIN * 2), (VIEW_AREA_HEIGHT - IMAGEVIEW_MARGIN * 2))] imageAddFrame:IMAGE_FRAME_SIZE withColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:FRAME_COLOR_R green:FRAME_COLOR_G blue:FRAME_COLOR_B alpha:FRAME_COLOR_ALPHA].CGColor] imageWithShadow:SHADOW_WIDTH];

    [backgroundImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - backgroundImageView.image.size.width) / 2, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - backgroundImageView.image.size.height) / 2, backgroundImageView.image.size.width, backgroundImageView.image.size.height)];
    
}
```

The `viewWillAppear` section is where the crash occurs, if I move some of the code to `viewdidLoad` then the app proceeds past the photo stage and continues, however when you go back to try it again, the app will crash out, so it's almost like a one-time fix but crashes the next time, but it gives some idea potentially of what is going wrong.

I realise it's hardcoded values, it's a very old app, I am just looking to bug fix before improving the other parts

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithShadow:(int)shadowSize {
    CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef shadowContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width + shadowSize, self.size.height + shadowSize, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                                       colourSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);
    
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(shadowContext, CGSizeMake(shadowSize / 2, -shadowSize / 2), 6, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextDrawImage(shadowContext, CGRectMake(0, 10, self.size.width, self.size.height), self.CGImage);
    
    CGImageRef shadowedCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(shadowContext);
    CGContextRelease(shadowContext);
    
    UIImage * shadowedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:shadowedCGImage];
    CGImageRelease(shadowedCGImage);
    
    return shadowedImage;
}
```

Edit - Stack trace below

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
    frame #0: 0x00000001ad11f4dc libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain_x2 + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001e2f2088c TelephonyUI`-[UIImage(TelephonyUI) imageWithShadow:] + 40
  * frame #2: 0x0000000104dea7cc Cut me in`-[PhotoSelectViewController viewWillAppear:](self=0x000000010637ed20, _cmd="viewWillAppear:", animated=YES) at PhotoSelectViewController.m:76:33
    frame #3: 0x00000001b5df2880 UIKitCore`-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 612
    frame #4: 0x00000001b5e8c6a8 UIKitCore`-[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 100
    frame #5: 0x00000001b5df4114 UIKitCore`-[UINavigationController viewWillAppear:] + 280
    frame #6: 0x00000001b5df2880 UIKitCore`-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 612
    frame #7: 0x00000001b5e8c6a8 UIKitCore`-[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 100
    frame #8: 0x00000001b64e4888 UIKitCore`__56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_3 + 740
    frame #9: 0x00000001b5f7391c UIKitCore`-[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 64
    frame #10: 0x00000001b5f73858 UIKitCore`-[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush] + 184
    frame #11: 0x0000000105c87f08 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    frame #12: 0x0000000105c897a0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #13: 0x0000000105c9834c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_drain + 920
    frame #14: 0x0000000105c97fa4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 40
    frame #15: 0x00000001b3edd9ac CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
    frame #16: 0x00000001b3ec1648 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2080
    frame #17: 0x00000001b3ec5d20 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
    frame #18: 0x00000001eb23c998 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 160
    frame #19: 0x00000001b615780c UIKitCore`-[UIApplication _run] + 868
    frame #20: 0x00000001b6157484 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 312
    frame #21: 0x0000000104de4054 Cut me in`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016b023670) at main.m:16:16
    frame #22: 0x00000001d167c344 dyld`start + 1860
```

Comment: Can you include a stack trace of the error/crash you’re experiencing?

Comment: Just added stack trace now

Comment: Apologies, the code was wrong - I have corrected it and edited original question to better suit the stack trace error.

Comment: The crash is coming from code you haven't posted yet. Post the `imageWithShadow` method.

Comment: @HangarRash I just corrected the code - my apologies.

Comment: You only posted `viewWillAppear`, not `imageWithShadow`. You are also missing the call to `[super viewWillAppear:animated];`. And yes, this is an old project. You still have the extremely out-of-date `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: I have posted that method now - appreciate it's old code, but strange how it crashes with iOS 16, and not 17?!

Comment: Try moving all of the `CGXXXRelease` calls to just before the `return`. And call the releases in the opposite order of the creates.

Comment: No Joy with that -  ok, if i remove the `:(BOOL)animated` from the `viewWillAppear` the app no longer crashes...However the selected image does not appear initially - but does AFTER the camera picture is taken.

Comment: If you remove the `:(BOOL)animated` part then you have invented your own method called `viewWillAppear` that is never called (compared to the standard `viewWillAppear:` method of `UIViewController`).

Comment: As suggested, did you add `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` ? Did you check if some values are `nil` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there is another implementation of a method named -imageWithShadow: somewhere (a private TelephonyUI framework from the looks of it), and it takes an object argument instead of an int (maybe an NSShadow argument).  And you are calling that method, not the one you think you are, and that method attempts to retain the object argument, but you are passing an int value of 8, so it dereferences 0x8 as a pointer to retain the argument, and crashes.   Change your imageWithShadow: method name to something more project-specific, maybe with a myapp_ prefix (always a good idea when adding category methods to standard Apple classes).

It's possible that TelephonyUI changed their method name in iOS17, or that your method "wins" there and TelephonyUI would crash it ever was needed.